# jQuery client side

Tags: jquery

I want to make a client side with jQuery and xml as my database.

I have found this: `$.twFile`

I don't know why my code doesn't work, because I can load the xml but I cannot add something to my xml?

Can anybody help me how I can add something to a client side from jQuery with xml as database?

The load method works:

```
var contacten = new Array();

var xmldoc=null;

//xml
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "Data.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: readXml
});

function readXml(xml) {

xmldoc=$(xml);

    $(xml).find("Contacten").each(function () {

        $(this).find("Contact").each(function () {

            var Id = $(this).find("Id").text();
            var Naam = $(this).find("Naam").text();
            var Functie = $(this).find("Functie").text();
            var Bedrijf = $(this).find("Bedrijf").text();
            var Foto = $(this).find("Foto").text();
            var Beschrijving = $(this).find("Beschrijving").text();
            var Adres = $(this).find("Adres").text();
            var Tel = $(this).find("Tel").text();
            var Email = $(this).find("Email").text();
            var Level = $(this).find("Level").text();
            var Group = $(this).find("Group").text();
            var Team = $(this).find("Team").text();

            contact = new Array(Naam, Functie, Bedrijf, Foto, Beschrijving, Adres, Tel, Email, Level, Group, Team);
            contacten.push(contact);
        });
    });
    createGui();
};

function createGui() {

    $.each(contacten, function (contactId, gegevens) {

        $('#contactlijst').append("<li id='" + contactId + "'><img src='img/pics/" + gegevens[3] + "'/><h2>" + gegevens[0] + "</h2><h3>" + gegevens[1] + " at " + gegevens[2] + "</h3></li>");
    });

}
```

The problem is when I need to add something to xml:

```
$.twFile.save("D:\foo.txt", "test")
```

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: `xmldoc=$(xml); $(xml).find("Contacten")...` I think thats funny.

Comment: Which browser are you trying to use? Don't expect it to work seemlessly, quite possibly the client needs to install plugins, set custom security settings for the website or allow some java to be run, etc.

Answer (score 0):

well you have to post back to server for that. Have you tried $.post ?

```
$.post(

    function(result){
        alert(z)
    }
)
```

hope this helps